# How do I solve the strange "filehandle" problem?

Tags: swift, filehandle

When I run the code below on my simulator iPhone 8, then it works fine. When I run it on my iPhone 8 then is "file" always nil. What do I wrong??

```
    func saveRobotData(nFile: String){
    if let sURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Foodgrease", withExtension: "csv"){
        let data = nFile.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        guard let dataU = data else {
            return
        }
        let file = FileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: sURL.path)
            print(sURL.path)
            file?.seekToEndOfFile()
            file?.write(dataU)
            file?.closeFile()
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't update a file in your main bundle, you need to store the file outside of your app if you need to modify it.

Comment: Have you a example of where I can place it outside my app?

Comment: Oke, I found it. Thx for your help Joakim.